# Problem importing existing Android project

Tags: java, android

So I got a new laptop and I setup everything but now, when I try to import an existing project I get all kinds of problems.

The console gives me this message...

> [2011-07-01 21:18:38 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
>
> [2011-07-01 21:18:38 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
>
> [2011-07-01 21:33:31 - Notepadv3] AndroidManifest.xml file missing!

Within the app the various classes are telling me to remove the `@Override` annotation. Any ideas??

Comment: Btw, I should mention I'm trying to import by going to file>new project>import from existing source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your compiler to JDK 6 from Prefrence -> Java -> comipiler and also when you import selet android project, I am assuming you .

Comment: Do you mean 1.6? compiler compliance level? That is what it's on and yes I select import Android project. I've done it many times on my other laptop no problems many times

Answer (score 0):

for your @Override problem: thats a java 1.5 vs 1.6 issue - java 1.6 allows @overrides for  implementations of interface methods - 1.5 not

Comment: It says my compiler compliance level is 1.6